# Redshift ODBC Driver test fails: Is the server running on host and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5439?

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-redshift

I have installed the 64x Amazon Redshift ODBC driver on my Windows 10 and it shows up under *System DSN* tab of *ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)*. I click on **Configure** and as I enter the connection information from my Amazon Redshift cluster properties, I face the following error:

[image]

Here are the current Network Security settings of the cluster. The only thing I have changed is that I have made it *Publicly accessible* (the value changed from No to Yes). But I haven't changed anything in VPC and VPC security group. As far as I see, all Inbound and Outbound traffic is allowed.

[image]

Anything I might have missed?
Should I add a firewall rule to my local machine for this port as well?

**UPDATE:**

Inbound rules for the VPC Group
[image]

Outbound rules for the VPC Group
[image]

Comment: What about the Secrity group?

Comment: @Marcin you mean the security group of the cluster and not the VPC? I can't seem to find it. Do you know where I find it?

Comment: On your screenshot you have edited VPC security group. Maybe this group blocks the connection?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, That's the VPC security group and it allows all Inbound and Outbound data. The Redshift does not reside in an EC2. So I am a bit confused about why do I get those VPC settings in the cluster.

Comment: RS cluster in VPC will have security group as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-vpc-security-groups.html). What is the source in the inbout roules?

Comment: @Marcin I updated the question with snapshots of both Inbound and Outbound rules for the VPC group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your security group (SG), you can notice that the `source` in the `inbound` rule is `sg-9054xxxx`. This means that all **internet traffic is blocked**.
You can only connect to your redshift from EC2 instance having same SG.

Alternatively, you can modify the `source` of the `inbound` rule in the SG to be your home/work ip address/range, or any IP address  (not recommended).

Other option is to setup a bastion instance in a public subnet with ssh connectivity. Then you can setup `ssh tunnel` between between your windows and redshift using the bastion. Similar for VPN connection.

To query redshift you may also use its [data api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html). This does not require establishing a regular connection to the cluster.

Comment: So, _All Traffic_ actually mean All Trafic is blocked? Ok, so I add my stations IP address as an Inbound rules and test?

Comment: @disasterkid Yes. Please test. I'm also adding other alternatives.

Comment: Absolutely. Let me test it out and come back to you.

Comment: No, _All Trafic_ means all traffic is allowed, but your source is setup to a fixed SG id. Which means _All traffic from this specific SG_. Change the source to allow traffic from anywhere to test connectivity.

Comment: @botchniaque What do you mean. That's what I wrote.

Comment: @Marcin Brilliant! I added an Inbound rule for _All Trafic_ but as *Source* I gave it only my own IP address. Would that be reasonable?

Comment: @disasterkid Glad it worked out. your IP would be better for security. If its all traffic, then anyone on the internet can try to connect to it. With your IP, you connections from your IP will be allowed only.